# Include leading zeros in boost spirit x3 parse results

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I wonder if it is possible to keep the leading zeros when parsing numbers with boost Spirit X3. What I currently have is a program (based on the employee sample) that parses integers into my datastructure. However, during parsing I lose the leading zeros. This is a problem for my application domain in which leading zeros in front of any integer give a different interpretation.

```
  #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
  #include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
  #include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
  #include <iostream>

  namespace client {
    namespace ast {
        struct number
        {
            int number;
        };
    }
  }
  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::number, number)

  namespace client
  {
    namespace parser
    {
        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
        using x3::int_;
        x3::rule<class number, ast::number> const number = "number";
        auto const number_def = int_;
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(number)
    }
  }

  int main()
  {
    using boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space;
    using client::parser::number;
    std::istringstream iss("1 02 030 00400 0005");
    std::vector<client::ast::number> nums;
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator iter(iss >> std::noskipws), eof;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(iter, eof, *number, space, nums);
    if (ok)
    {
        std::cout << "parsed: " << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << nums[i].number << "\n";
        }
    }
  }
```

The result of the program is:

```
  parsed:
  1
  2
  30
  400
  5
```

whereas I need

```
  parsed:
  1
  02
  030
  00400
  00005
```

**EDIT**

I made some progress in this regard:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f06f02613956230

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace ast {
    struct fullnumber
    {
        std::string leadingZeros = "";
        int number = -1;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::fullnumber, leadingZeros, number)
x3::rule<class fullnumber, ast::fullnumber> const fullnumber = "fullnumber";
auto const fullnumber_def = x3::lexeme[-(+x3::char_("0") >> &x3::int_) >> +x3::int_];
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(fullnumber);

int main() {
    std::vector<ast::fullnumber> fullnumbers;
    std::string parse_numbers_input("0 1 00 01 20 003000 00004 500000");
    auto begin = parse_numbers_input.begin();
    auto end = parse_numbers_input.end();
    bool ok = phrase_parse(begin, end, *fullnumber, x3::space, fullnumbers);
    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "parsed: " << std::endl;
        for (auto n : fullnumbers)
            std::cout << "leading: '" << n.leadingZeros << "', num: " << n.number << "\n";
    }
}
```

```
parsed: 
leading: '0', num: 0
leading: '', num: 1
leading: '00', num: 0
leading: '0', num: 1
leading: '', num: 20
leading: '00', num: 3000
leading: '0000', num: 4
leading: '', num: 500000
```

As you can see I am already close to what I want. The trick was to understand that x3::lexeme is required because if we don't use that the parser will always use the splitter between each element. So
      x3::lexeme[-(+x3::char_("0") >> &x3::int_) >> +x3::int_];
says: [optional] all zeros that are followed by an integer (non-consuming), followed by an integer.

I just have another question about what the parser is doing:

```
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| id | input    | leading  | number    | expected |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 1  |   0      |     0    |    0      |    no    |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 2  |   1      |          |    1      |    yes   |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 3  |   00     |     00   |    0      |    no    |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 4  |   01     |     0    |    1      |    yes   |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 5  |   20     |          |    20     |    yes   |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 6  |   003000 |     00   |    3000   |    yes   |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 7  |   00004  |     0000 |    4      |    yes   |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
| 8  |   500000 |          |    500000 |    yes   |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------|
```

- For 1 I expect leading="", num="0"
- For 3 I expect leading="0", num="0"

How come the 0 is found twice in these cases?

Comment: Why you are storing it as `int` then? `std::cout << (0 * 10)` will print `0`, not `00`.

Comment: You make a valid point here. I store the numbers as an int because in the end I need a numeric interpretation but maybe I should do a 2 level parsing: first parse all as string and then extract my information before I transform it into my semantic number. I am just new to spirit and have not much knowledge. I also didn't know X3:: raw until the other answer.

Comment: You showed an expected output of the example and with `int` type it cannot be achieved, what is making your example invalid. Usually it is not a big problem if the question contains issues not related to a end-goal (it is not about Spirit parser either), but in your example it affects the result. Probably the main reason you are still not satisfied with an answer that was given to you is because the question is lacking important details.

Comment: The update has changed the parsing idea into a leading char and remaining int part. So it is now possible to store the input in these fields. I also show that it currently works but I am puzzled about 2 results. It is a clear spirit question about the parser. I would be happy to understand/modify the parser to fulfill my initial demand.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other commenter said, just parse as strings.

If you still want the convenience of Spirit's `int_` parser to parse (signed) integers, wrap it in a `raw[]` to propagate to iterator-ranges (which are compatible with strings):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c0c8dac6e8d034d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss("1 02 030 00400 0005");
    std::vector<std::string> nums;
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator iter(iss >> std::noskipws), eof;

    bool ok = phrase_parse(iter, eof, *x3::raw[x3::int_], x3::space, nums);
    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "parsed: " << std::endl;
        for (auto num : nums)
            std::cout << std::quoted(num) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
parsed: 
"1"
"02"
"-030"
"00400"
"0005"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, albeit getting a compiler warning with that code (I dont like warnings ;-) ) it seems ot works fine. However, I thought what I really want is some kind of optional 0 followed by a number. so I tried these 2 but the parsing fails: Any idea why?

      auto const num_def =
       -x3::char_("0")
      >> +x3::int_
      ;
or 
      auto const num_def =
       *x3::char_("0")
      >> +x3::int_
      ;

Comment: How could I parse trailing zeros as string and the rest of the number as integer (Optional trailing zero and mandatory number also for the special case of parsing 0 in no trailing and the number 0)?

Comment: 1. what warning (this seems like a no brainer, you can see online it compiles without a warning, maybe just edit that http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c0c8dac6e8d034d and add the flag that creates the warning?)

Comment: 2. what do you mean? trailing!=leading. Your comment doesn't seem to match any of the previous question/code

Comment: I am very sorry. I mixed up leading and trailing and for sure, they contradict each other. I am interested in LEADING zeroes.

Comment: I checked your sample again and it compiles without warning. My warning came from a different line of code. So sorry about that too.

Comment: Regarding my expected result: Getting the leading zeros as string and the rest of the number as an integer I am still wondering why I am failing to parse "00" into leading: "0",  number: "0". My guess is that it may be to the fact that x3 parsers are recursive descent PEG parsers and from my interpretation they are greedy in such a way that the first parser that matches will consume the input as long as possible. So 00 will be matched and eaten by the *char_("0") statement and the following +int_ parser will fail and such the complete parser assembled from both parsers will fail. Correct?

Comment: Given my assumption is correct I should be able to match with a positive lookahead. Maybe my assumption or my input is wrong. I tried to create a lookahead with "&" and I am still not able to get what I want. 
auto parser = (*x3::char_('0') > & x3::int_) >> *x3::int_; results in 
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library. Debug Error! abort() has been called.

Comment: It looks as my greedy interpretation is correct. I have made some progress: -(+x3::char_("0") >> &x3::int_) >> +x3::int_ (optional zeroes before an int, integers) works nicely on "00" and "01" but fails for "00 01". So I am still missing something here. When I use the parser for this input string "00 01 20 003000 00004 500000" I am getting leading: '000', num: 500000. Where did spirit find the leading '000'?

Comment: It's probably the case of non-atomic backtracking kleene-matching. I'll give it a look after I put my children to bed and have a coffee :)

Comment: You have to make another decision. How did you intend to treat "00 01 20 -003000 +00004 500000"? (I mean, compare: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8096b81ecb343d71). I think it's time to re-evaluate why you "need" this.

Comment: I dont see any issues with leading +/-. They can appear upfront of my numbers. The problem I need to solve is to parse so called trailing zero surpression format in which we know how long a number is (lets say 8 digits) and where the implicit decimal point is. Lets say we have a 00012300 and know the decimal point is at position 5. Then what is called full format is 00012300, in leading surpression format it is 12300 and in trailing surpression format it is 000123 but all have the meaning of "12.3". You could combine signs upfront.

Comment: well, I want to understand how I can parse full format, leading zero supression and trailing zero supression format. The full format is fixed point, leading zero supression is also fixed point but trailing zero supression is something slightly different I would say.